# Update table from converted value in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to compare between an int value and a converted (varchar to INT) value in one table to find a value in another table then update it through phpmyadmin.

comment table

```
id: 1   title:Lorem   postID: 15
```

meta table

```
ID:99   NewID: 123 Type: "older_id"   Value:"15"
```

SQL

```
update t1
set t1.postID = t2.NewID
from comment t1
inner join meta t2
on t1.postID = CAST(t2.value AS INT)
where t2.Type = "older_id";
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong but i keep getting an error.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using MySQL (which is typical with PHP), then the right syntax is:

```
update comment c join
       meta m
       on c.postId = (p2.value + 0)  -- this converts the value, although even this is not necessary
    set c.postID = m.NewID
    where m.Type = 'older_id';
```

There is no `from` clause in MySQL.

Comment: Allow me to give you the points to reach 1M and a gold tag badge at the same time... Congrats on an amazing achievement.